# Json in a Dataframe field in Scala in a recommender engine

Tags: json, dataframe, scala, apache-spark

I'm trying to build a recommender engine based on a web store that sells house products.
I'll keep this simple for the example. Using scala and Spark.

I have a dataframe that contains 4 fields.

```
1. A unique ID   (INT)
2. A ProductName  (String)
3. A ProductPrice  (Number)
4. ProductCategories (Json field)
```

I also have a second dataframe, which contains sales of these products.
Anyway, I was looking at a movie recommender engine example, and it was fairly straightforward. Using the movie lens dataset. I was hoping to transpose that over to here to this products example.
However, the ProductCategories, per product can look like the following:

e.g.

```
[{'id': 28, 'type': 'Home'}, {'id': 18, 'type': 'Kitchen'}, {'id': 53, 'type': 'Living'}]
[{'id': 28, 'type': 'Home'}, {'id': 23, 'type': 'Bathroom'}]
```

When I load the data into a dataframe, it's a json string.

Here is some dataframe code:

```
val ProductsDF2 = ProductsDF1_temp1.select(ProductsDF1_temp1.col("id"), ProductsDF1_temp1.col("product_name"), ProductsDF1_temp1.col("product_price"), ProductsDF1_temp1.col("product_categories"))
```

How do I manipulate the code, so the dataframe extracts the categories out of the product_categories (json) into their own columns like here:

| id | ProductName | ProductPrice | Home(Boolean) | Kitchen(Boolean) | Living(Boolean) | ... etc

I think this is what i need to achieve, to get the recommender engine working.
Kinda like one hot encoding, I believe.

Any suggestions would be appreciated. I'm a little new to this.

Thanks
Con

Comment: what is your expected output out of these 2 datasets?

Comment: I'm new to recommender engines. I'm hoping that by parsing out the categories of the products, that this will help with recommending a product, to a fresh buy of product X.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope you find this useful

```
// Let us assume that the dataframe is defined as a variable df
// we need to parse the string json array data in column_name column which is available as a json string

df.show

// output of df

+----------------------------------------------------+
|column_name                                         |
+----------------------------------------------------+
|[{"id":28,"type":"Home"},{"id":18,"type":"Kitchen"}]|
+----------------------------------------------------+

df.printSchema()

root
 |-- column_name: string (nullable = true)

// Following is my answer

import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.json.JSONArray

// This udf converts the json array to an array of json string

val toArray = udf { (data: String) => {
    val jsonArray = new JSONArray(data)
    var arr: Array[String] = Array()
    val objects = (0 until jsonArray.length).map(x => jsonArray.getJSONObject(x))
    objects.foreach { elem =>
      arr :+= elem.toString
    }
    arr
  }
}

val df1 = df.withColumn("column_name", toArray(col("column_name")))

df1.printSchema()

root
 |-- column_name: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
   
val df2 = df1.withColumn("column_name", explode(col("column_name")))

// here we are extracting the data from the json string using the schema of the json string data

val schema = spark.read.json(df1.select("column_name").rdd.map(x => x(0).toString)).schema

df2.withColumn("column_name", from_json(col("column_name"), schema))
   .select(col("column_name.*"))
   .show(false)
   
// Final output

+---+-------+
|id |type   |
+---+-------+
|28 |Home   |
|18 |Kitchen|
+---+-------+
```

**Edit:**
Please include the following maven dependency for importing `org.json.JSONArray`

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.json</groupId>
    <artifactId>json</artifactId>
    <version>20201115</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Oh thanks, I'll take a look. Amazing.

Comment: "Too many arguments for constructor JSONarray in class JSONarray."

I've imported:
import org.apache.hadoop.shaded.net.minidev.json.JSONArray

Is this correct?

Comment: @JetS79 please import `import org.json.JSONArray`. Please look at the whole code I have also mentioned the imports.

Comment: When I put in: import org.json.JSONArray
Is complains and says: "value json is not a member of org - did you mean org.json4s?" 

If I say yes and import json4s instead, then this line gives an error:
val jsonArray = new JSONArray(data)

Specifically it complains on "data". It says: 
"too many arguments for constructor JSONArray in class JSONArray: ():org.apache.hadoop.shaded.net.minidev.json.JSONArray"

How do i get this to work? Thanks by the way.

Comment: may I know what build tool you are using, if you are using any that is. If you are using `maven` then please add the dependency I have given in your `pom.xml` file. I don't know why it is not working for you. It works for me.

Comment: I am using sbt. scalaVersion := "3.1.0"
sparkVersion = "3.2.0". What is the full dependency name/version it needs? Thanks

Comment: Please find the SBT dependency here [link](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json/20201115). it is idependent of scala or spark version.

Comment: Thanks. When I put that SBT ref in, the code complains on the import statement at the top of my code. It says: "value json is not a member of org - did you mean org.json4s?", the same again

Comment: Sai, I set up the project again carefully, making sure I got everything in the build.sbt file set up correctly. Correct versions of everything. Scala, spark, etc. I have now overcome that specific error and I'm wiring up the solution you gave. When I get it working I'll update you. Thanks a million. You're a star.

Comment: Apologies, this line here is not working for me:

df2.withColumn("column_name", from_json(col("column_name"), schema))
   .select(col("column_name.*"))
   .show(false)

It says "tasks not serializable".

I made a mistake in my initial question.
I said the json looked like: [{'id': 28, 'type': 'Home'}, {'id': 23, 'type': 'Bathroom'}]
I was wrong, It looks like: {'id': 28, 'type': 'Home'}, {'id': 23, 'type': 'Bathroom'}

Without square brackets. How do i get it to work?

Comment: You can try extending your main class or object with `Serializable` - `object ojectName extends Serializable` if you are running on cluster mode. I don't know why it is not working for you. The json string doesn't look like a valid json. you can try concatanating a square bracket at the beginning and in the end and use the same code.

Comment: That worked just now as you described. I put in extends serializable and I concatenated the square brackets at each end. Sai, you are a legend and I thank you greatly. You've really helped me out and I am grateful. Thanks!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242451/discussion-between-jets79-and-praneeth-sai).